# Rename file with Filename Date

Tags: powershell

I have some CSV files which I want to rename:

```
gmclrmp.full.20160210.csv
gmclrmp.full.20160120.csv
```

I would like to rename the files to `2016-02-10.csv` by the date on the file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve all [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) files and rename them using the `Rename-Item` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\tmp -Filter '*.csv' | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.*?(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$1-$2-$3' }
```

Comment: I get an error: Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: I just realised I need the 2016-02-10 as 2016-10-02 instead.

Comment: So change  the replace to $1-$3-$2

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 cd C:\temp
 $yourfilename="gmclrmp.full.20160210.csv"
 rename-item $yourfilename $($yourfilename.Insert($yourfilename.Length - 6, "-").Insert($yourfilename.Length - 8, "-").Substring($yourfilename.Length - 12))
```